# I am unable to use button click event in XML android

Tags: android, xml

1.

I am calling the imageView @id "image" dynamically from gridview. Without calling imageView button click is working but after calling its not working ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sh2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />



   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take your Picture"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="btn1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/image" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: From grid view I am passing an image and in new activity I want to take a picture along with that passed image.

Comment: try remove  ## Heading ##

Comment: sry that thing came by mistake...##Heading## is not there in the code..

Comment: Got the answerThe problem is the object for the button newPicButton is being created as a local object which is valid only in the scope of the function onCreate and as soon as the code exits that function the garabage collector deallocates the object for the button. what you need to do is declare the newPicButton object outside any method and then in onCreate method assign it a listener. This will solve your problem and i hope i have explained why nothing happens when you remove the code for the newPicButton in the onActivityResult method :)